# Make Python logger print to file and not to console

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I'm fairly new to the logging module, but after reproducing some of the code I've looked up on the internet but I can't find a solution for this.
Currently, my logger is printing to both the file and the console, even though it should only be doing it to the file

My code:

Main.py

```py
import logging,logging.config

....

if __name__=='__main__':

    fh=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('avisador.log')
    fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    fh.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S'))
    rootlog = logging.getLogger()
    rootlog.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    rootlog.addHandler(fh)
```

In a diferent file I have a function called by this Main one

Secondary.py

```py
import logging

startlog=logging.getLogger('startweblog')

def Startroutine():
    ....
    startlog.info('We have started')
```

I get this in bot the console and the file

```
15-Oct-2020 14:39:44 - INFO: We have started
```

I've tried with the following `rootlog.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)` in hopes the handler `fh` still wrote to the file thinking it was the root the one printing to the console, but what I got is nothing was printed in either place.

How should this be configured so it only appears in the file?

Comment: Your provided code only output to file. Did you call `logging.basicConfig` somewhere? Please add a minimal reproducible example of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call **logging.basicConfig** like this:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='avisador.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
```